# How can I duplicate a daily datetime value across all 5min datetime rows of same day following concat/merge/join?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am concatenating two dataframes with datetime formatted rows. I would like to replicate the daily value from df_b across all rows in df_a for the relevant day.

For example, df_b dataframe is:

```
logtime    | df_b_value
2017-05-01 | 10.19
2017-05-02 | 10.01
2017-05-03 | 11.34
```

I would like to create:

```
logtime             | df_a_value | df_b_value
2017-05-01 06:05:00 | 14.5       | 10.19
2017-05-01 06:35:00 | 14.5       | 10.19
2017-05-01 06:45:00 | 20.0       | 10.19
2017-05-01 07:15:00 | 20.0       | 10.19
2017-05-01 07:55:00 | 10.0       | 10.19
2017-05-01 08:05:00 | 10.0       | 10.19
2017-05-01 09:05:00 | 10.0       | 10.19
```

So far I have tried using `concatdf = pd.concat([df_a,df_b], axis=0)`, however, all of my daily formatted values are moved to the tail of the df.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` is just placing one DF over the other. It will not give you the final output you are looking for. What you need to use is `merge`.

**Code**

```py
import pandas as pd

mergedf=pd.merge(df_a,df_b,how='inner',on='logtime') #Assuming this is an inner join. You can use left/right/outer depending on the output you need
```

**EDIT**

Highlighting an answer by @Code Different showing how to `merge` based on logtime of one `df` alone, as asked by @danwri :

[Can I join two dataframes while only retaining rows based on datetimes featured in the second dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395185/can-i-join-two-dataframes-while-only-retaining-rows-based-on-datetimes-featured/59399195#59399195)

**Code**

```py
pd.merge_asof(df_a, df_b, on='logtime')
```

Comment: Great! Thank you - One issue is that hours, minutes and seconds are lost when merging this way. Eg. all logtimes become 2017-05-01. Will look into also.

Comment: @danwri That's because one df has time while the other does not. If you need time as well, you will have to make sure df_b has it. Once you have time in both df, the inner join will do an exact match.

Comment: Thanks @Gary - Seems not quite there with the answer, but will see if I can crack it. I've tried to duplicate the logtime w/ minutes into a separate column and then merging with the plan of then replacing the logtime w/ days, but minutes still disappear. Will update when figured out.

Comment: The solution was `pd.merge_asof` as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395185/can-i-join-two-dataframes-while-only-retaining-rows-based-on-datetimes-featured/59399195#59399195) - if you can edit your answer @Gary based on this, happy to accept as the answer, otherwise will update my question :)

Comment: @danwri Nice, this is some new learning for me as well, thanks for sharing! I have updated my answer to include this post!